# ListView stealing focus form EditText after reload

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext, focus

So I have an `EditText` and a `ListView` below it. I'm listening for the `KEYCODE_ENTER` to be pressed and after that, I'm adding an entry to the listview's adapter and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` method. Surprisingly, but after that, the very first item in the listview becomes focused instead of previously focused `EditText`.

Here is my layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
        android:singleLine="true"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here's what I do when the enter key is pressed

```
mTextEdit.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {


            // modifying data set
            onScanDataReceived(mTextEdit.getText().toString().trim());

            BaseAdapter adapter = (BaseAdapter) mListView.getAdapter();

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            mTextEdit.setText(null);

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
});
```

The problem is clearly with listview reloading, because when I comment out the line `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` the focus is still on the `EditText`.

Is there any method to keep the focus on the `EditText` after reloading the `ListView`?

P.S. I've tried call `requestFocus()` on the editText after I reload the data to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
mTextEdit.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {


                // modifying data set
                onScanDataReceived(mTextEdit.getText().toString().trim());

                BaseAdapter adapter = (BaseAdapter) mListView.getAdapter();

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                mTextEdit.setText(null);
                Handler mHandler = new Handler();
                mHandler.postDelayed(
                        new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                mTextEdit.requestFocus();
                            }
                        }
                        , 50 // 50...for delay in my case
                );

                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Well, this is definitely going to work(not always, though, as the delay time is rather arbitrary), but I was seeking for more 'bulletproof' approach.

Comment: Anyhow, it works, I've decided to stick with safe 200ms.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
mTextEdit.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
mTextEdit.requestFocus();
```

If you want focus with softkeyboard also. Write the below codes after above code

```
final InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(mTextEdit, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

Comment: I don't care about the softkeyboard, as I'm using another means of input. And setting `setFocusableInTouchMode` to `true` does not help in my case unfortunately.